# Calculating average in 8086 assembly - ending a loop

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, dos

I am trying to calculate the average, I can input in the program but I can't stop the loop and see the ( average )

Here is my sample code.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
        VAL1         DB      ?
        DISPLAY1     DB      0AH,0DH,'HOW MANY NUMBER OF STUDENT SCORES DO YOU WANT TO INPUT? :','$'
        DISPLAY2         DB      0AH,0DH,'ENTER NO:','$'
        DISPLAY3         DB      0AH,0DH,'AVEARGE:','$'
    BUFFER       DB      3,4 DUP(?)
.CODE
MAIN    PROC

.STARTUP

        LEA DX,DISPLAY1 ; loads the message in the variable display 1
        MOV AH,09H  ; interrupt function to display the message
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,0AH  ; Read into buffer
    INT 21H
    SUB AL,30H

    MOV CL,AL
    MOV BL,AL   ; moves the content of al to bl register
        MOV AL,00   ; sets the value of al to zero, the value of al is now in bl register
        MOV VAL1,AL ; stores al in val1 NB: al is still zero.

        LBL1:
        LEA DX,DISPLAY2 ; displays message in display 2
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,0AH  ;Read into buffer
    LEA DX,BUFFER
    INT 21H
    SUB AL,30H

        ADD AL,VAL1 ; add val1 to al i.e, it now adds the previous value to the new one.
        MOV VAL1,AL ; saves the added value to val 1.
        LOOP LBL1   ; continues too add.   

        LBL2:
        LEA DX,DISPLAY3 ; displays character in display 3
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H

        MOV AX,00   ; sets ax value back to 00
        MOV AL,VAL1 ; moves the total value back to al
        DIV BL      ; divides the total value with the inputed number of values tht was stored in bl
        ADD AX,3030H    ;  convert to ASCII
        MOV DX,AX   ; now moves the content of ax register to data register
        MOV AH,09H  ; this displays the result
        INT 21H

.EXIT

MAIN    ENDP
        END     MAIN
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're not accoutning for the `CX` register to get stomped on by your interrupt calls.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer None of the DOS calls the OP uses trash `CX`. He just didn't set it up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

### You're not using the correct input function!

> ```
> MOV AH,0AH  ; Read into buffer
> INT 21H
> SUB AL,30H
> ```

When using DOS function 0Ah, you won't find anything useful in the `AL` register afterwards.
You're still learning how to do this, so make your life a bit easier and start with the simplest of input functions.

```
MOV  AH, 01h  ;Wait for a key
INT  21h
SUB  AL, 30h
xor  cx, cx
mov  cl, al
```

See how I put the count in the word sized `CX` register instead of the byte sized `CL` register? Later in the program the `loop` instruction that you use depends on this fact.

---

When inputting all the students' scores stick with the same small numbers and use the same input function. **Only when this program works should you try to input larger (multi digit) numbers.**

---

When it comes to calculating the average, you only need the quotient of the division. Turn it into a character and display it with the correct output function 02h.

```
xor  ax, ax   ; sets ax value back to 00
MOV  AL, VAL1 ; moves the total value back to al
DIV  BL       ; number of values was stored in bl
ADD  AL, 30h  ; convert to ASCII
mov  dl, al
MOV  AH, 02h  ; this displays the result
INT  21h
```